# Tem como fazer uma select de comparação de registros duplicados?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela com 57 campos, devido a um descuido no passado não criei o campo PEDIDO como Unique Key
Devido ao uso por mais de um usuario em uma tela do sistema ele acabou permitindo a duplicidade de alguns registros e ao longo do tempo hora o sistema pegava um registro hora outro pra atualizar (esse vou ter mais problemas pra acertar), mas alguns registros estão exatamente iguais e a unica coisa que os diferencia é um campo que sempre crio nas tabelas chamado codkey, que é um sequencial dessa forma minha tabela esta assim:

Exemplo de dados:

```
codkey  pedido campo1 campo2 campo3 etc
  1      123   valor1 valor2 valor3
  2      123   valor1 valor2 valor3
  3      123   valor1 valor2 valor3
  4      123   valor1 valor2 valor3
```

Sei que posso fazer um select colocando a comparação de cada campo no where, mas são 57 campos e isso está me dando um custo de tempo e a incerteza se o resultado será confiável

Exemplo:

```
select * from tabela a
inner join mv_tabela b on(b.campo1 = a.campo1)
  and(b.campo2 = a.campo2)
  and(b.campo3 = a.campo3)
where (a.pedido = b.pedido)
```

A minha pergunta é: Existe algum comando no SQL que facilite isso?

Estou usando PostgreSQL

Comment: por que você mantém tudo isso em base? por que não deleta os repetidos e passa a usar o único?

Comment: @rLinhares essa duplicidade acabou atrapalhando alguns updates porque hora ele atualizava um hora outro, então tenho informações em uns registros que preciso preservar, vou ter que ver o que tenho que preservar atualizar o registro mais novo pra depois excluir o duplicado que ficará obsoleto, será uma trabalho manual, não tem como, são 256 registros, pra analisar linha a linha, mas duplicados são mais de 2 mil, então quero eliminar esses duplicados que estão exatamente iguais pra ficar menos trabalhoso

Comment: Só considera duplicados se os 57 forem iguais ? Faz um cursor ou select se a linha for igual a anterior deleta. A ūnica coisa e comparar os tais 57 https://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/forums/topic/63846-resolvido-eliminar-registos-duplicados-postgresql/

Comment: O único campo diferente é o codkey que é a chave primária, vou procurar a respeito de cursores, não sou muito bom em funções do PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra fazer usando a [Window Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) `ROW_NUMBER`.

Nesse código, eu criei uma coluna para fazer uma especie de "classificação" dos registros. Quando a coluna **rownum** for igual a 1, significa que é o primeiro registro único do resultado.

A unicidade é configurada pelas colunas especificadas na clausula `PARITION BY`. Inevitavelmente, você teria que informar as 57 colunas nessa clausula, mas acho que não seria difícil.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tabeladuplicidade 
(
   codkey INT NOT NULL,
   pedido INT,
   campo1 TEXT,
   campo2 TEXT,
   campo3 TEXT
);
ALTER TABLE tabeladuplicidade ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tabdup_codkey PRIMARY KEY(codkey);

INSERT INTO tabeladuplicidade VALUES 
     (1, 123, 'valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')
   , (2, 123, 'valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')
   , (3, 123, 'valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')
   , (4, 123, 'valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')
   , (5, 456, 'valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3');

WITH q AS 
(
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pedido, campo1, campo2, campo3 ORDER BY codkey) rownum
      , *
   FROM tabeladuplicidade
)
SELECT * FROM q
WHERE q.rownum > 1 -- Se for maior que um, é duplicidade
```